How to use Nginx Proxy Manager for Flutter Web Application and Supabase using one domain name but different subfolder
I have a similar question to this post but I am not sure why is there a config file involved since the Nginx Proxy Manager is GUI . I was given a server with public IP address and a domain name.  This will host several web applications that are each in a Docker container, specifically Flutter Web Applications and a self-hosted Supabase.  I need to host the web apps as subpages since I have already a domain name, i.e. example.com/app1, example.com/app2, etc. I need them to have SSL certificates. I came upon the Nginx Proxy Manager upon researching and I have installed it also using Docker.
How can I set it up as a reverse proxy?  Logging in Nginx Proxy Manager, I tried to create a Proxy host. I entered in the Domain Names example.com/app1, where example is the given domain name and working if accessed directly.  I added /app1 in the domain name, but I have not configured any nginx conf file nor install it, I only have the Nginx Proxy Manager. I entered the public IP address in the Forward Hostname/IP and the Forward Port for exampel 8000 for the self hosted Supabase.  Using the IP address with the port, the website is accessible but using the domain name with the subfolder, i.e. example.com/app1, it shows "404 Not Found".  What else is missing for the configuration? Do I still need to install Nginx and configure even though I have already the Nginx Proxy Manager. I also need to install certificates later.
